# How to find time of board column entry and exit for Azure DevOps in Power BI Desktop?

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, analytics

I have many queries (and resultant views) working in Power BI with OData queries... but one has me stumped, and I believe I need to move from simple OData into multiple queries with a script in Power BI it self...

The goal is to report the Entry and Exit times for each work item from each Board Column.  There are samples on the Internet about how to do this for State.... but that is NOT what I am looking for.

The following gets all work item revisions, but no Board information (A work item can be on multiple boards, and the column is specific to the board:

```
let
    Source = OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/wintellectaccelins247playpens/WorkItemPlaypen04/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItemRevisions?$filter=Area/AreaPath eq 'WorkItemPlayPen04\Accelins247\Intelligent Ingestion\Submission Monitoring' and WorkItemType eq 'User Story'", null, [Implementation="2.0"])
in
    Source
```